# Requesting a resource results in a 404 (Flask)

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

As I'm testing the URL endpoint for a resource, I'm getting a `404 Not Found` error. I don't understand why it cannot be found as the resource is added to the `api` instance and the blueprint is added to the flask app.

**tests.py**

```
def test_todo_collection_resource(self):
    with app.test_client() as client:
        http_response = client.get("/todos/")
        json_data = http_response.get_json()

    self.assertEqual(http_response.status_code, 200) <<<---FAILS
    self.assertTrue(http_response.is_json)
    self.assertTrue(all(
        (instance['name'] in self.todo_resources.values()
            for instance in json_data)
    ))
```

**todos.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify

from flask_restful import Api, Resource, fields, marshal

from models import Todo

todo_api = Blueprint("resources.todos", __name__)
api = Api(todo_api)

todos_fields = {
    'name': fields.String
}

class TodoList(Resource):
    pass


api.add_resource(
    TodoList,
    ''
    'todos'
)
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, g, jsonify, render_template
from config import HOST, PORT, DEBUG

from peewee import *


import models
from resources.todos import todo_api

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(todo_api, url_prefix="/todos/")

models.DATABASE.init('todo_api.db')
models.initialize(models.User, models.Todo)


@app.route('/')
def my_todos():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=HOST, port=PORT, debug=DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined any methods in your `TodoList` class that is why there is a 404 error as it can't find any HTTP methods defined on that endpoint. The [Flask-RESTful documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#resourceful-routing) specifies defining HTTP methods in your Resource class e.g.

```
class TodoList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return TODOS
```